# Javascript - accessing password in ssh2 connection

Tags: javascript, exec

I have a class which is being used to connect to a device.  I have made in instance of the class in my application

app.js

```
myConn = new myConnection();
```

myConnection.js

```
function myConnection(){    
     this.settings = {
        host: '192.168.225.195',
        port: 22,
        username: 'sysadmin',
        password: 'pass'
    };
}
```

I have a function within said class that executes a command on the remote device but that requires a password.  When this happens stderr.on is executued and I send the password and a newline char.

```
myConnection.prototype.installPatch = function(callback){   
    this.conn.exec('sudo -S bash /tmp/update.sh', function(err, stream){
        var standardMsgs = '';
        var errorMsgs = '';
        if(err) throw err;
        stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {                
            callback(standardMsgs, errorMsgs);       
        }).on('data', function(data) {
            standardMsgs += "<br>" + data;
            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);            
        }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            errorMsgs += data;
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            stream.write(myConn.conn.config.password + '\n');
        });
    });    
}
```

While this works I am not a fan of accessing the password with

```
stream.write(myConn.conn.config.password + '\n');
```

since a change to the name "myConn" in app.js would required the same change in the "installPatch" function.

I had intended to use

```
stream.write(this.settings.password + '\n');
```

Do I have any other options that will allow me to retrieve the password from within the myConnection class?  I hope I am just overlooking the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I believe it was starring me in the face.

Change

```
stream.write(myConn.conn.config.password + '\n');
```

to

```
stream.write(stream._client.config.password + '\n');
```